# how to stop a while loop to enter, in the same variable

Tags: c

I have to enter random names and weights and finish the loop when I hit enter instead of the name. However the way I used to detect the enter does not serve to take the name so getting two variables. The question is how to put the enter of the test and name using the same variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main() {

    int c, weight[1000], i = 0;
    char name[1000];
    puts ("Enter the person's name or only enter to end the program");
    if ((c = getchar() == '\n')) {




    } else {

        while (c != '\n') {
            printf("Enter the name");
            scanf("%s", &nome[i]);
            i++;
            printf("Enter the \n");
            scanf("%i", &weight[i]);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try [`strlen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)

Comment: and btw, never use `scanf("%s")` -> buffer overflow. use `fgets()`.

Comment: Try checking for EOF instead of \n.

Comment: ah and finally: a `char` is a **single** character.

Comment: The code block after `while (c != '\n')` does not modify `c`, so it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Given all these errors, again time for the [rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[1000] = {0};                      // initialise
    puts ("Enter the person's name or only enter to end the program");
    if (fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) != NULL) {
        name [ strcspn(name, "\r\n") ] = 0;     // remove trailing newline etc
        if (strlen(name)) {
            printf("The name entered was: %s\n", name);
        } 
        else {
            printf("You did not enter a name\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `names` is an array of characters and you're treating it like an array of strings. Secondly, loops that need to exit based on input are most clearly expressed with `break`:

```
char *names[1000];
int count = 0;

while (1) {
    char *r, buf[1000];
    int len;

    char *r = fgets(buf, 1000, stdin);
    if (NULL == r) break;                 // EOF
    if ((len = strlen(buf)) < 2) break;  // NL only

    r = malloc(len + 1);
    if (NULL == r) break;
    strcpy(r, buf);
    names[count] = r;
    count += 1;

    ...
}

...
```

Comment: I'd expect the `'\n'` to be removed rather than saving in `names[]`.